Adaptive Card Building for Teams Workflow Array Access Error
I'm trying to get a teams workflow integration for a product I use, I don't understand how I could access all the data under what name because the alert is sent in an array and there would be no name for it.
I'm using the Adaptive Card Preview Extension in VSCODE to see if it works.
card.json
{
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "version": "1.4",
    "body": [
      {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "${ROOTARRAY[0].root.content.body.items.text}", <=== 
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "size": "Medium",
            "wrap": true
          },
          {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "9"
          },
          {
            "type": "FactSet",
            "facts": [
              {
                "title": "Started (UTC):",
                "value": "2021-04-01T19:40:10Z"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "Container",
        "items": [
          {
            "type": "FactSet",
            "facts": [
              {
                "title": "Title:",
                "value": "string"
              },
              {
                "title": "Title:",
                "value": "string"
              },
              {
                "title": "Title:",
                "value": "string"
              },
              {
                "title": "Title:",
                "value": "string"
              },
              {
                "title": "Title:",
                "value": "string"
              },
              {
                "title": "Title:",
                "value": "string"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "actions": [
      {
        "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
        "title": "View",
        "url": "https://openalert.com/.../.../"
      }
    ]
  }

Here is what's sent from the server
card.data.json
[
  {
    "content": {
      "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
      "body": [
        {
          "items": [
            {
              "size": "Medium",
              "text": "string",
              "type": "TextBlock",
              "weight": "Bolder",
              "wrap": true
            }
          ],
          "type": "Container"
        },
        {
          "items": [
            {
              "facts": [
                { "title": "Name:", "value": "string" },
                {
                  "title": "Description:",
                  "value": "string"
                },
                { "title": "Title:", "value": "string" },
                { "title": "Title:", "value": "string" },
                { "title": "Title:", "value": "string" },
                { "title": "Title:", "value": "string" },
                { "title": "Title:", "value": "string" }
              ],
              "type": "FactSet"
            }
          ],
          "type": "Container"
        }
      ],
      "type": "AdaptiveCard",
      "version": "1.5"
    },
    "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive"
  }
]

I've tried root (becuase that is how you get access to data in the first layer in an adaptive card) content and leaving it blank. I'm

Could you please share the error which you are getting? and also share the repro steps to try at our end?

Could you please share the above details?
